# Suddenly got WebForm_InitCallback is not defined in EPiServer edit mode

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, episerver

EPiServer CMS 6 site that suddenly got this error in edit mode. Found alot of posts saying something about changing the system time could cause this but this is not relevant to my case.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Stig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually the Global.asax that caused this problem. Not exactly sure what the problem was in the global.asax but if I set the global.asax to inherit from EPiServer.Global insted of the codebehind it worked great. (Yes, the codebehind inherited EPiServer.Global) I guess that resulted in missing HTTP handlers or something :)

Comment: That's odd, there shouldn't be any problems inheriting your own Global class (as long as it in turn inherits EPiServer.Global like you said).

Oh well, if you don't NEED your own Global class I guess the problem is "fixed" for now. :)

Comment: this damn thing took a full day of me to solve, I deleted the global asax and compiled project and created the same global.asax and compiled and it worked both in iis express of visual studio and actual windows server with iis

Answer (score 0):

Which ASP.NET version are you running? Off the top of my head I'd say it sounds like you're missing an HTTP handler in web.config.

Comment: running ASP.NET 4. I thought so too but I cant figure out what changes I could have made that would cause this... What handlers comes to mind?